# Sealing fully cast-in floor joists

Tags: basement, foundation, joists, caulking

My house built in 1928 has concrete filled spaces between the floor joists and rim joist. There are gaps in some of them, some 1" wide with most being very small. I suspect these gaps could be the source of some mice we've caught along with leaking air.

What is the best method and products to fill these gaps to prevent air loss and from rodents entering?[image: Gaps]

Answer (score 1):

I've read a lot and corresponded with folks on the Building Science Corp. website GreenBuildingAdvisor.com. about my own 1901 stone carriage house.  Also, I hire and work with (and learn from) a very experienced Rockland County, NY stone mason, James Jones.

He would say, just patch with a similar material to the concrete such as a patching cement? Just do a very thorough job, packing it in well.
Most of the spray foams absorb water eventually (if there is any moisture) and break down.

A construction sealant like a Sika product (Home Depot) would do for smaller cracks, but if the concrete has held up, I'd fill it with a similar cementitious material.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment, "Expanding spray-foam fixes everything".

Since it's used to seal window and door installations against wooden studs without rotting them, it's highly unlikely that it would rot out floor joists.

Comment: I agree except for the rodent issue. I'm not sure they wouldn't tunnel their little way right through if they smelled anything tasty.